# JavaScript Accoridon - Auto scroll to top of open accordion

Tags: javascript, html, accordion

I am trying to set up my accordion so that when a user clicks on one of the headings, the page will automatically scroll down to the top of the heading and show the open panel for that accordion item.

However, the problem I have currently is that with the code I have implemented, my screen is scrolling up, so that the heading of the accordion item, sits right at the bottom of my screen, therefore the content in the panel is off screen.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="accordion" style="margin-bottom:30px"><b>Heading 1</b></div>
<div class="panel">
  <p class="text-light">Text 1</p>
</div>
<div class="accordion" style="margin-bottom:30px"><b>Heading 2</b></div>
<div class="panel">
  <p class="text-light">Text 2</p>
</div>
```

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var panel = document.getElementsByClassName('panel');

for (var i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
 acc[i].onclick = function() {
    var setClasses = !this.classList.contains('active');
    setClass(acc, 'active', 'remove');
    setClass(panel, 'show', 'remove');

    if (setClasses) {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
    }

    document.body.scrollTop = this.offsetTop;
 }
}

function setClass(els, className, fnName) {
  for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    els[i].classList[fnName](className);
  }
}
```

Comment: I should use anchors to jump to the right place. Once succesful, animate the jump using js/jquery.

Comment: You should use pure CSS for such a purpose. Have a look at http://codepen.io/abergin/pen/ihlDf and http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/02/21/accordion-with-css3/

Answer (score 0):

`this.offsetTop` shows relative position to parent's element top. You should get the position relative to the top of your window. This code should work for you:

```
document.documentElement.scrollTop +=this.getBoundingClientRect().top
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment! That solution doest seem to work, whenever i click on an accordion, the screen does not move, it just stays where it was previously